# How to change the value of parameter?

Tags: verilog, hdl

I designed an ALU that does 4 operations depending on the value of op-code, and I used `generate` for conditional calling of sub module that I have, according to the project specification.  But, how can I change the value of the parameter to move from one operation to another?

```
module ALU (A4, B4,cin4);
input [7:0] A4, B4;
input  cin4;
//input [1:0] opc; 
wire [7:0]out4;
wire cout4;
parameter opc=0;
generate     
    case (opc) 
        0: alu_add  u1(out4,cout4,A4,B4,cin4); //calling an alu_add module   
        1: alu_sub  u2(out4,cout4,A4,B4,cin4);
        2: alu_comp u3_1(B4,out4); 
        3: alu_xor  u4 (A4,B4,out4);
    endcase 
endgenerate
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are for constants, and therefore can not be changed during simulation. Parameters can be overridden during instantiation.

What concerns me though is the use of the term `call` in the question. Generates are used to generate hardware based upon constants, ie they do not dynamically create and destroy hardware.

u1 to u4 are instances, describing physical hardware, what you have written at the minute is a ALU which can only do one thing. The code is configurable and given the user a choice of 4 things but once instanced then it is fixed.

To make a generic Generic ALU with all four operations available operations you need to select the output from the required ALU ie:

```
module ALU (
  input [7:0] A4, 
  input [7:0] B4,
  input  cin4,
  input [1:0] opc; 
);

wire [7:0]out4, out4_0, out4_1, out4_2, out4_3;
wire cout4 ,cout4_0, cout4_1;

alu_add  u1(out4_0,cout4_0,A4,B4,cin4); //calling an alu_add module  
alu_sub  u2(out4_1,cout4_1,A4,B4,cin4);
alu_comp  u3_1(B4,out4_2); 
alu_xor  u4 (A4,B4,out4_3);

  always @* begin  
    case (opc) 
      0: out4  = out4_0; 
      1: out4 = out4_1;
      2: out4 = out4_2;
      3: out4 = out4_3;
    endcase 
    case (opc)
      0: cout4 = cout4_0;
      1: cout4 = cout4_1;
      default:  cout4 = 'b0;
    endcase
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to instantiate a sub module inside a condition. this is an important part from the project specification. Is there a way?

Comment: @FaithRashed Inside a runtime condition (condition which changes at runtime)? NO verilog can not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can override a parameter's value when you instantiate the module.  For example:

```
ALU #(.opc(1)) i1 ();
ALU #(.opc(2)) i2 ();
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2012, Section "23.10.2.2 Parameter value assignment by name".